# UITableViewController Xib not being used in iOS5 (working in iOS 6)

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, interface-builder, tableview

I have several ViewControllers which subclass UITableViewController and have a Xib file where I set the TableViews appearances (style, colours etc) and add a header and footer.

There xib files do not appear to be getting loaded on iOS 5. On iOS 6 the xib is loaded and the view looks as expected.

iOS 6

[image]

iOS 5
[image: iPad iOS 5.1]

Xib - Interface Builder

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that prior to iOS 5 the UITableViewController designated initialiser did not load the Nib. This changed with iOS 6 and it now checks for a Nib.

To make the app work with both version I have made my designated initialiser call

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"Nib Name" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank.
It's OK for Me

i add a method '`initWithMyNib`' 
i replace '`initWithStyle`' with '`initWithMyNib`'

```
(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

(id)initWithMyNib:(NSString*)strNibName
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:strNibName bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```